# jquery mobile listview search filter start typing detect

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to detect when a user start type intp jquery mobile list view filter input. 
Also get which buttons user type.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
    <li><a href="#id">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="#id">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#id">BMW</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help would appreciated.

Note : This is a PhoneGap app.

Comment: http://craig.is/killing/mice you could use this for the keylog part. Or write it yourself, which would be more efficient i guess.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Can it be still useful for a PhoneGap Application which is intended to be run on iphone and Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how to do it. Im posting it if anyone have same question.

```
$('div.ui-input-search').delegate("input", "keyup",
        function(e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code != 8) {

                //Any key other that backspace clicked

                var text = $(this).val();
                if (text.length == 1) {


                    //Just Started Typing
                }

            }
        }
);

$('div.ui-input-search').delegate("input", "keydown",
        function(e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 8) {
                // BackSpace is clicked.
                var remainingText = $(this).val();
                if (remainingText.length == 1) {


                       //Cleared all characteres

                }

            }
            // console.log(code+'\n\n\n');
            // var remainingText = $(this).val();
            // console.log(remainingText);
        }
);
```